# Reading the file and replacing the JSON value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json object as below. How can I change the value of all json keys by the values which is saved in file.

```
var 
    {
        "name": "john",
        "city": "CC"
    }
```

I am not worried about the key here, just want to change the value sequentially according to the value given in file

```
File.txt
mark
MM
```

Below is the code which im trying

```
fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    //console.log(data);

    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {

        data.forEach(function(user){
            key = user;
            console.log(key);
        });

    })   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `var` is not allowed in JSON because it's reserved keyword. your JSON file should be:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "city": "CC"
}
```

Your iterator function needs to be improved and use `require` function instead of low level `fs` API:

```
var obj = require("./your-data-file.json");

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
})
```